# Is it possible to give a var to and innerHTML id?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm still learning JavaScript and I'm unsure whether it's possible to give a variable to an ID.

```
<div id="example"> Code </div>
```

Can I use the `document.getElementbyID("example").innerHTML` and just equal it to a var?

Comment: Do you mean `document.getElementById("example").innerHTML`?

Comment: `var text = document.getElementById("example").innerHTML`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the result of a `getElementById(...).innerHTML` in a variable, but it can't be used to update the value of innerHTML later. It's just a plain string. The below snippet should make this clear. Notice how the `divInnerHTML` never gets updated even after the text is changed.

```js
var divInnerHTML = document.getElementById('example').innerHTML;

console.log(divInnerHTML);

divInnerHTML = 'hi'
console.log(divInnerHTML);

var div = document.getElementById('example');
div.innerHTML = 'new html';
console.log(divInnerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="example">html</div>
```